# How to attach the Safari Debugger to the simulator in a turbo-ios native app

Tags: ios, turbo, turbo-ios

I want to attach the Safari Debugger to the simulator in a [turbo-ios](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-ios) native app. According to [Joe Masilotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384110)'s [blog post](https://masilotti.com/debug-turbo-native-apps-with-safari/), you need to add the following code

```
    let webView = WKWebView()
if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
    webView.isInspectable = true
}

let session = Session(webView: webView)
```

I cannot work out where to put this code. I have tried to do this in the class `SceneDelegate` as follows

```
private let webViewConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = {
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = " IOS-xyz/1.0"
    // Enable inspection for Safari debugger
    if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
        configuration.isInspectable = true
    }
```

but this gives an error

```
Value of type 'WKWebViewConfiguration' has no member 'isInspectable'
```

So where do I put this code?

For context, here is the entire SceneDelegate Class, which is fairly standard for turbo-ios apart from the use of WKWebViewConfiguration.

```
import UIKit
import Turbo
import WebKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    private lazy var navigationController = UINavigationController()
    
    private let webViewConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = " IOS-xyz/1.0"
        return configuration
    }()

    private func visit(url: URL) {
        let viewController = VisitableViewController(url: url)
        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        session.visit(viewController)
    }

    // Initialize the Turbo Session with the custom configuration
    private lazy var session: Session = {
        let session = Session(webViewConfiguration: webViewConfiguration)
        session.delegate = self
        return session
    }()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        visit(url: URL(string: "http://myserver.com/sessions/new")!)
    }
}

extension SceneDelegate: SessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: Session, didProposeVisit proposal: VisitProposal) {
        visit(url: proposal.url)
    }
    
    func session(_ session: Session, didFailRequestForVisitable visitable: Visitable, error: Error) {
        print("didFailRequestForVisitable: \(error)")
    }
    
    func sessionWebViewProcessDidTerminate(_ session: Session) {
        session.reload()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isInspectable` is a property of `WKWebView` and it's not available within `WKWebViewConfiguration`.

```swift
private let webViewConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = {
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = " IOS-xyz/1.0"
    // other configuration
    return configuration
}()

private lazy var session: Session = {
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
    if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
        webView.isInspectable = true
    }
    let session = Session(webView: webView)
    session.delegate = self
    return session
}()
```

[image]

Comment: @Obromios ok I got it. `Session` has a public init function that allows passing a webView as a parameter. I edited the answer above.

Comment: Tested on their demo and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, glad I could help.